# Headers authentication value is always the authentication token of my app even if I set it to the access token of the api I want to call

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, header, http-headers, calendly

I am trying to call calendly API using the access token generated from their website, the problem is it doesn't matter which value I set for authorization in my headers, I keep getting error 401, and when I checked the network tab in the browser, I found out that the authorization value is not the value I set earlier in the code but instead it's the value of my app's jwt token.

Here are the different ways I tried to set my headers

```
getCalendly(){
    console.log("get is called")
    // this.headers = new HttpHeaders()
    // .append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    // .append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT")
    // .append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization")
    // .append('Authorization', 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dGguY2FsZW5kbHkuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjM1MTU2MTc5LCJqdGkiOiI1ZGY5MDI2Mi1jZmNmLTRjZTYtOTZlYi1jODlhZDA4NzBiYzgiLCJ1c2VyX3V1aWQiOiJCSEVDWVBINDQ1NUdWTENSIn0.Of90aRiUObfUd5k3pucI1UqCdputy7vkSOxxsrTM_-k')

    // const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    // .set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    // .set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT")
    // .set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization")
    // .set('authorization', 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dGguY2FsZW5kbHkuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjM1MTU2MTc5LCJqdGkiOiI1ZGY5MDI2Mi1jZmNmLTRjZTYtOTZlYi1jODlhZDA4NzBiYzgiLCJ1c2VyX3V1aWQiOiJCSEVDWVBINDQ1NUdWTENSIn0.Of90aRiUObfUd5k3pucI1UqCdputy7vkSOxxsrTM_-k');

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization",
      "authorization": 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dGguY2FsZW5kbHkuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjM1MTU2MTc5LCJqdGkiOiI1ZGY5MDI2Mi1jZmNmLTRjZTYtOTZlYi1jODlhZDA4NzBiYzgiLCJ1c2VyX3V1aWQiOiJCSEVDWVBINDQ1NUdWTENSIn0.Of90aRiUObfUd5k3pucI1UqCdputy7vkSOxxsrTM_-k',
    });

    return this.http.get<any>(
        "https://api.calendly.com/event_types?user=https://api.calendly.com/users/BHECYPH4455GVLCR", {headers: headers});
  }
```

and each time when I check the value of authorization in network it's not the token I wrote her but instead it's my app's token.

P.S: When I tried to call the API from a new project without jwt token everything works totally fine.

Comment: You should search for an interceptor that adds the auth header to every request. Try to add some logic there, if the URL is not your backend's, then don't add the auth token in the header.

Comment: Octavian, you are right, after I found the interceptor and added an if condition just to overwrite the authorization header if there is no header sent it worked, thanks a lot